Module not found: Error while trying to build application
I am upgrading my application dependencies and I am stuck on the below error when I am trying to build my react application (npm run build):
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /path/to/my-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
I am using webpack@5.0.0, @babel/runtime@7.9.0 & react-dev-utils@12.0.1 in my application. Below is my .babelrc file
{
  "presets": [
[
  "@babel/preset-env",
  {
    "targets": {
      "node": "current"
    }
  }
],
"@babel/preset-react",
"react-app"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"
  ]
}


The only solution that worked for me to get rid of this error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70984860/17574536

Importing files from outside the src directory is prohibited by create-react-app, which is why I believe the problem occurs. You may be seeing a build failure because the webpack is attempting to include a file from @babel/runtime' in node_modules`.
Update your dependencies to the most recent version to resolve this issue using:
npm install react-dev-utils@latest webpack@latest @babel/runtime@latest

If it didn't fix the problem then you can try to create a symlink to make CRA treat the @babel/runtime files as if they're inside src. You can try these commands:
mkdir -p src/helpers/babel-runtime
ln -s ../../../node_modules/@babel/runtime src/helpers/babel-runtime

Next, you might try deleting everything from your node_modules folder and reinstalling everything.
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
npm run build

Hope it helps.
